# Can billiards fill any figure?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, billiards

For any 2D closed shape, is there always a point and angle for which the billiard movement of a ball fully completes the interior of the shape? In other words, does the path eventually converge to the full figure?

For example, will the moose be completely filled?

[image]

If not, can you provide an example of a figure for which a ball shot from any point, at any initial angle, will not fully cover the interior?

Comment: This is the [illumination problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illumination_problem)

Comment: Billiard problems are subtle and hard. That's true of even the simplest ones. For example, it is [unknown whether every obtuse triangle has a periodic billiard path](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344053/why-is-the-billiard-problem-for-obtuse-triangles-so-hard).